# trying to get a blob from an oracle DB using spring3 and mybatis

Tags: spring, mybatis

I am working on a project re factoring an old j2ee project to spring3/mybatis

I am currently having problem retrieving a PDF saved as a blob in an oracle table.

The original code returns a byte[] of 135896bytes and the spring/mybatis returns byte[] of 86bytes. So am i doing something incorrectly. Thanks for any help

The original code looked like::

```
        byte[] filebytes = null;
        con = SvcsConnection.getDBConnection("drugdb");
        String qry = "SELECT pm_blob FROM pdf_master WHERE pm_id_seq = '" +id + "'";
        oracle.sql.BLOB blob;
        stmt = con.createStatement(); 
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);    
        //set mime type
        if(rs.next()) {
            blob = ((OracleResultSet) rs).getBLOB("pm_blob");
            filebytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());                                 
        }
```

filebytes after the getBytes is **135896bytes**

in my spring stuff i have the following

**mapper**

```
<select id="getPdfMaster" parameterType="int"  resultType="org.uhs.formulary.pdf_master.model.Pdf_Master">
    SELECT pm_id_seq, pm_filename, pm_title, pm_blob, pm_update_datetime, pm_update_source,
     to_char(pm_update_datetime, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as pm_update_datetime_str
     FROM pdf_master WHERE pm_id_seq = #{pm_id_seq}
</select>
```

**DAO**

```
@Repository
public interface PdfMasterDao {
    public List<Pdf_Master> getPdfMaster(int pm_id_seq);
}
```

**Model (snippet)**

```
public byte[] getPm_Blob() {
    return pmBlob;
}
```

getPm_Blob returns a byte[] of 86 for the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the jdbcType as blob

```
<resultMap id="kpDataMap" type="KPData">
        <id property="kpId" jdbcType="INTEGER"  column="KPID" />
        <result property="fName" jdbcType="VARCHAR" column="FNAME" />
        <result property="lName" jdbcType="VARCHAR" column="LNAME" />
        <result property="salary" jdbcType="BIGINT" column="SALARY"/>
        <result property="img" jdbcType="BLOB"  column="IMG" />
    </resultMap>

    <insert id="setKPData" parameterType="KPData">
        INSERT INTO KPDATA(KPID,FNAME,LNAME,SALARY,IMG)
        VALUES(#{kpId},#{fName},#{lName},#{salary, javaType=java.math.BigInteger, jdbcType=BIGINT},#{img,  jdbcType=BLOB})
    </insert>

    <select id="getKPData" resultMap="kpDataMap">
        SELECT KPID,FNAME,LNAME,SALARY,IMG 
        FROM KPDATA
        WHERE KPID=#{kpId}
    </select>


public class KPData {

    private int kpId;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private BigInteger salary;
    private byte[] img;

        //getters and setters


}
```